# контекстное меню в ListView

Tags: java, android, android-context-menu

Можно ли в `ListView`, при долгом нажатии, вызывать контекстное меню?
В моем `ListView` все элементы состоят их строкового массива, который загружается из базы данных. Сейчас, как аналог, использую `Activity` в диалоговом стиле.

PS: пожалуйста, не перенаправляйте на английские сайты (у меня с ним плохо и я знаю, что это плохо). А лучше скиньте код, который нужно прикрепить к `ListView`, остальное я сам разберу.

Вот код создания `ListView`:

```
ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dictionaries);
lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Если вы работаете с БД, то для этого существует `CursorAdapter`, который работает напрямую с записями в БД. Перегонять данные из БД в какие то массивы и потом выводить уже эти массивы - непрактично, громоздко, медленее и этот дополнительный слой данных не нужнен совсем.

Comment: К сожалению, я так еще не умею...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получить классическое контекстное меню по долгому клику на айтеме `ListView` вам нужно проделать несколько нехитрых действий:

Зарегистрировать свой список в качестве виджета, реализующего контекстное меню:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ..
    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1); 
    registerForContextMenu(lvMain);      
    }
```

Создать это контекстное меню:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

разметка *context_menu.xml* для контекстного меню, содержащая отображаемые пункты (поместить в папку res/menu/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/edit"
          android:title="@string/edit" />
    <item android:id="@+id/delete"
          android:title="@string/delete" />
</menu>
```

Создать обработчик для выбранного пункта в меню:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
   case R.id.edit:
     editItem(info.position); // метод, выполняющий действие при редактировании пункта меню
     return true;
   case R.id.delete:
     deleteItem(info.position); //метод, выполняющий действие при удалении пункта меню
     return true;
   default:
     return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

метод  `item.getMenuInfo()` возвращает объект [`AdapterContextMenuInfo`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.html) с некоторой информацией по тому пункту в списке, на котором вызвано контекстное меню:

1. *long id* - ID элемента в выбранном пункте списка, если он есть ( например при работе с БД).
2. *int position* - позиция выбранного пункта в адаптере списка.
3. *View targetView* - возвращает айтем в виде View

В данном примере в методы обработки кликов `editItem` и `deleteItem` передается позиция того пункта в адаптере, на котором вызвано контекстное меню.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы очень помогли! :)

Comment: Если не секрет: где Вы этому научились?  Книги/курси или еще что-то?  Я смотрю уроки startandroid.ru, но там многого не рассказывают.

Comment: A как получит позицию элемента ListView, для которого вызвали ContextMenu? У меня не выходит так сделать!

Comment: в данном примере `info.position` содержит номер позиции, для которой вызвано контекстное меню. Если у вас что то не получается, то вы делаете что то не так и "у меня не выходит" недостаточное описание проблемы.