# Как открыть контекстное меню с помощью ContextView для кликанного элемента ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview

Данные на `ListView` заполнились из БД. Теперь мне нужно открыть контекстное меню при долгом ( 2-3 секунды) нажатии на элемента `ListView` и там предлагать удалить и изменить выбранные данные на БД. В Гугле нашел, что-то похожее. Сначала надо регистрировать `ListView` для контекстного меню

```
// добавляем контекстное меню к списку
registerForContextMenu(lvData);
```

А потом вот это:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, CM_DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.delete_record);
}
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {
         // получаем из пункта контекстного меню данные по пункту списка 
         AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
         // извлекаем id записи и удаляем соответствующую запись в БД
         db.delRec(acmi.id);
         // обновляем курсор
         cursor.requery();
         return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

[Источник](http://goo.gl/cSp5tJ).

Но я ничего не понял. В прошлый раз точно такая проблема у меня было с курсором. Нашел хорошую статью и всё стало ясно. Но по этой проблеме ничего не могу найти. Все выкладывают листинг а объяснение не дают.

Comment: Вот эти варианты достаточно понятны? [Раз](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/373124/17609) и [два](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/450863/17609)

Comment: И приведите ссылку в нормальный вид. По сокращённым ходить не хочется. И поясните что именно вам не понятно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пример 2 это то что мне было нужно. Спасибо. Не понял только одну вещь. Где разместить обработчик `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {` ? Внутри цикла чтении из базы?

Comment: По идее это надо делать в классе активити или фрагмента.